# Visual Studio 2010 Setup Project 64 bit create registry key issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, installation

I have a 64 bit setup project with a 64 bit windows service exe and dlls. In my installer class i create registry keys with this code:

```
using (typeKey = typeKey.CreateSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Folder\Folder\Folder"))
        {
            typeKey.SetValue("Type", 0);
            typeKey.Close();
        }
```

But it keeps creating registry keys at SOFTWARE\WOW6432NODE\SOFTWARE\FOLDER\FOLDER\FOLDER.
Btw setup copies exe and dlls under 64bit program files folder. No problem in copying folders to 64 bit folder.

Any idea?

Comment: Are you sure the installer app is 64 bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using .NET 4, use the new [RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey.openbasekey.aspx) method and pass RegistryView.Registry64

Answer (score 2):

This happens because your custom action uses a 32-bit process. Perhaps this article will help:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2006/02/01/64-bit-managed-custom-actions-with-visual-studio.aspx

Basically, you need to either make it use a 64-bit process or call a function that can write in the 64-bit registry hive.