# How to create custom registry key 'Programmable' targeted on 64bit OS with VS2010 registry editor

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, excel, registry, windows-installer

In the registry view, I manually created `Programmable` key using the following path `HKCR\CLSID\{MYGUID}\Programmable`. I think there's no problem on 32-bit OS.

However, on 64-bit OS, `Programmable` somehow gets missed. I guess it probably has something to do with registry redirection on 64-bit. Taking a look at the 
 registry, I find `CLSID\{MYGUID}` is actually located @`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{MYGUID}`
 and there is no `Programmable` key created under `{MYGUID}`.

So my question is - do I have to manually specify the `Programmable` key @`HKLM\SOFTWARE\CLasses\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{MYGUID}\Programmable` as well? Do I need to change the target platform to `x64`?

Comment: You'll need to create a 64-bit installer.  Not just because of the Programmable key, also because of the CLSID.  Easy to do in a Setup project, just change the PlatformTarget property from x86 to x64.

Comment: @HansPassant Yeah I thought about it too, but my concern is, would the DLL be built as 64-bit DLL instead of 32-bit? The Excel is still 32-bit process but just running on a 64-bit windows. Is my concern unnecessary?

Comment: It is if you only care about 32-bit Excel.

Comment: Actually i just read the other post where you gave the answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7384270/visual-studio-2010-setup-project-64-bit-create-registry-key-issue

Comment: I am looking at using that openBaseKey method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you are asking but it certainly seems that you are facing a problem caused by [registry redirection](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896459) of a 32 bit process on 64 bit Windows.

This problem only occurs on 64 bit Windows. If your application requires some values in the registry you should set these values using a tool that runs using "the same number of bits" as your application. For instance you can use Regedit:

- Your application is a 32 bit application: Use 32 bit Regedit (`%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\regedit.exe`).
- Your application is a 64 bit application: Use 64 bit Regedit (`%SystemRoot%\regedit.exe`).

If for some reason you want to use a 64 bit tool to set registry keys and values for a 32 bit application you need to understand how registry redirection is performed. For instance, `HKLM\Software` is redirected to `HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node`. The details are explained in the Microsoft Support article linked above.

Comment: I guess I didn't describe it very clearly, as I was looking for the help regarding registry setups in VS setup project, questions like what kinda custom keys do I need to create in the installer. But thanks for the link anyway. it's good to know.