# How Is This Returning NULL

Tags: c#, windows, registry

My C# application license manager is returning NULL when checking for a Key's existence even though the key exists and my application is installed. I have tried running as an Administrator and add or removing backslashes in the Key path.

```
        RegistryKey LitenUpKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\LitenUp\NIT", false);
        if (LitenUpKey == null) {
            // Registry Key NOT Found
            return false;                
        }
```

[image: proof it exists]

**NOTE: I am building as x64!**

Comment: are your code is 32bit ? and which error returned ?

Comment: @RbMm As stated it is reurning null when it should not be.

Comment: I mean error code, which containing reason - why fail (dont know how this look in c#). and your code is 32 or 64 bit ?

Comment: in case *x64* code - of course - key not exist - why you look under *wow6432node* ? you need use `KEY_WOW64_32KEY` access

Comment: @RbMm Your sentence doesn't make sense, please rephrase it. :)

Comment: @RbMm It was generated under wow6432node...

Comment: if 64bit code want access  32-bit key it must use [`KEY_WOW64_32KEY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384129(v=vs.85).aspx) access. you in code use `SOFTWARE\LitenUp\NIT` and it 64bit - so why you in regedit look under `SOFTWARE\wow6432node\LitenUp\NIT`?

Comment: @RbMm But, both applications are 64 bit and execute as such.

Comment: *both applications* - in question visible only one application. if another application create key under *Wow6432Node* - it or 32bit or explicit use `KEY_WOW64_32KEY`. you need determinate for self - under which node you want create key and based on this - explicit use `KEY_WOW64_64KEY` (better) or `KEY_WOW64_32KEY` access

Comment: @RbMm Can you link to a website where you learned about `KEY_WOW64_(64)or(32)KEY`. I want to learn more but your English no offense is making it very hard. Both the applications are x64 bit.I wrote to the key using `Registry.OpenSubKey("...").SetValue("item", "value")`.

Comment: [Registry Reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384235(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @RbMm pointed out, the issues was in registry reflection between 32 bit and 64 bit. The following question showed me how to choose which view I saw. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11808462/avoid-registry-wow6432node-redirection) it is.