# Get Uninstall Command For a Certain Program in C#

Tags: c#, registrykey

so I am working on this code that returns an uninstall command string to uninstall a certain program.
I have seen this code in other questions, but no one seems to have the same problem as me.
This is the code:

```
public static string GetUninstallCommandFor(string productDisplayName)
    {
        RegistryKey localMachine = Registry.LocalMachine;
        string productsRoot = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Products";
        RegistryKey products = localMachine.OpenSubKey(productsRoot);
        string[] productFolders = products.GetSubKeyNames();

        foreach (string p in productFolders)
        {
            RegistryKey installProperties = products.OpenSubKey(p + @"\InstallProperties");
            if (installProperties != null)
            {
                string displayName = (string)installProperties.GetValue("DisplayName");
                if ((displayName != null) && (displayName.Contains(productDisplayName)))
                {
                    string uninstallCommand = (string)installProperties.GetValue("UninstallString");
                    return uninstallCommand;
                }
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
```

This code returns this error:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

> products was null.

I don't know how products can be empty, I did check that subkey and it was full of folders, so how can I solve this problem.

Comment: Given that error message, there is zero chance that `products` is not null.  So you'll need to work out why`localMachine.OpenSubKey(productsRoot);` didn't return anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build for X64.  In a 32bit process you're actually reading `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node` through [registry redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/registry-redirector).

Or you can request an un-redirected view of the registry per:
[Avoid Registry Wow6432Node Redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11808462/avoid-registry-wow6432node-redirection)

Comment: I think I would have designed `OpenSubKey` so that it throws a meaningful exception instead of silently returning nothing.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply I am going to read the link you gave me, and will be back to you.

Comment: @RobertHarvey agree.  It should have used the "TryParse pattern", eg `bool TryOpenSubKey(KeyName, out RegistryKey )` if they wanted to avoid throwing exception, but I think that pattern didn't really show up until .NET 2.0.