# C# HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE Registry edit working in VS (Debug) but not when published to .exe

Tags: c#, windows, registry

I have a requirement for an application to "run on start-up" for all users. This has to be setup by the application it's self, not by a user adding a shortcut to start-up folder or something similar. I have managed to get this to work by adding the .exe path to the registry Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run. The following code successfully adds the path to the registry when in debug mode and visual studios is run as administrator.

```
using Microsoft.Win32;

var path = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run";
try
{
    string baseDir = "EXAMPLE_DIR";
    using (RegistryKey? key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(path, true))
    {
        if (key is not null)
        {
            string exePath = $@"{baseDir}\iOK2.exe";
            key.SetValue("iOK2", exePath);
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

However the same code fails to add to the registry when it has been "Published" to an an executable (.exe) file.
[image: Admin published executable]

The code doesn't produce any errors, it seemingly executes and exists successfully. I have tried running as admin, creating an app.manifest and requiring admin, ensured it's compiled to 64-bit and is accessing the correct registry
Any ideas on what is happening or something I'm missing? If this fails I could potentially call a PowerShell script to edit the registry, but would rather keep dependencies to a minimum if at all possible

Comment: You could use [ProcMon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to see the registry accesses

Comment: 32 or 64 bit? There are separate registries for them https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/deployment/view-system-registry-with-64-bit-windows

Comment: @Charlieface Just discovered when run in Visual Studio (x86) nothing happens (same as when published to exe) however when on AnyCPU it works fine. SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run is the 64-bit registry though isn't it?

Comment: @Charlieface Just checked, you are correct they are being put into HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node...\Run registry, I thought that was 32-bit registry though, anyway issue solved I guess. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Avoid Registry Wow6432Node Redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11808462/avoid-registry-wow6432node-redirection)